# Add a shape ontop of a PImage

Tags: processing

I am currently making an application similar to Microsoft Paint and the like, though I have run into a small problem due to lack of knowledge.

I am currently trying to allow users to draw atop of an image (PImage) they have loaded, an example being:

```
ellipse(p.x,p.y,radius,radius);
```

Which works fine and all if the image were loaded and then left alone, then the ellipse were drawn; however, because I am continually loading the image with draw() it is as if the ellipse were never made to the user.

Is there a way to attach this ellipse to the background PImage so it will be visible to the user? Just to create the ellipse ontop of the background or something?

I am sorry to ask this as it is probably simple, but I cannot find much about it through given documentation of the language. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to approach this.

You could draw your image only once, from the `setup()` function.

You could draw all of your shapes to a `PGraphics`, which is a bit like an image that you can draw to. Then draw that `PGraphics` to the screen after you draw your image. The `createGraphics()` function might come in handy here.

Or you could maintain a data structure that contains all your shapes, and iterate through that and draw them each frame. This would be useful if you want to support an undo button.